# Defining shared library in Typescript and Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I have ProjectA set up compiling and running in Visual Studio with Typescript. I now want to set up ProjectB, and use some of the code from ProjectA

So if my directory structure is:

```
c:\workspace\ProjectA\src
c:\workspace\ProjectB\src
c:\workspace\shared\src
```

is it possible to edit ProjectA and ProjectB .csproj files to point to the shared typescript code?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested this by placing the shared files (the TypeScript file and associated files) in a shared folder and then using `Add > Existing Item` and selecting `Add As Link` when I add the files.

If you are using reference comments, you'll need to use the relative path - if you drag the shared file onto a local TypeScript file it will generate this for you:

```
/// <reference path="../../Shared/Logger.ts" />
```

You will need to consider your deployment strategy. One way to do it would be to set the JavaScript files to copy on build, so they would all appear in your bin folder.

You might also want to consider packaging your shared stuff - you could make NuGet packages for them for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is that I want to share a folder full of subdirectories and ts files. So I want to "Add an Existing Folder" (and all its contents), but the IDE doesn't seem to offer this as an option. I will look at NuGet though.

Comment: The add-as-link option works for files, so it will be a bit painful if you have a lot to add. NuGet would allow you to do the lot and keep in in sync across multiple projects.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround by editing the csproj file. You need to put in a entry for each subfolder, but for my case where I have lots of shared files, this is worthwhile. Using this method, all the files in a subfolder are also listed in the Solution Explorer.

```
<Content Include="..\..\shared\*">
    <Link>src\shared\f</Link>
</Content>
<Content Include="..\..\shared\subfolderA\*">
    <Link>src\shared\subfolderA\f</Link>
</Content>
<Content Include="..\..\shared\subfolderB\*">
    <Link>src\shared\subfolderB\f</Link>
</Content>
```

The Link element shows the path as it will appear in the Solution Explorer. Note the extra \f at the end of the Link path. This can be any string and, for whatever reason, makes the parser interpret it in the way we want.

I've marked Steve Fenton's answer as correct since it is probably the best approach for most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently dealing with this problem.  Here's how I got things running for me without dependencies on the other project.

I made my application with the source .ts files to run on my local IIS machine.

I then added reference to the js files in my testrunner file to point to the localhost address.

To write the tests and have access to the .ts files I just make added a copy as link file to my Typescript folder in my test runner project.

this worked pretty well for me.  Thought I'd share.

Answer (score 0):

By using Fenton's solution I was able not just to reuse source from project A, but also to debug it from project B. Solution behaves almost like project A is a class library.

Project A is a web app written in TS (empty web project template). Project B is UWP wrapper around Project A with some additional functionality. Here is the solution structure:

```
Solution
- Project A (ASP.Net Web Application)
  - Scripts
    - TS
      - (all ts files)
      - tsconfig.json
    - App
      - ts.js, ts.js.map, ts.d.ts (these three are result of compilation)
- Project B (UWP JS)
  - Scripts
    - App
      - ts.js, ts.js.map, ts.d.ts (these three are added as links from A) 
    - TS
      - (additional functionality)
```

Now, you can use breakpoints in Project A ts files while debugging Project B.