# Typescript module() and AMD use result in unsharable code

Tags: typescript

Scenario1:

I have a project with 2 Typescript files that look like this:

```
// file:/app/Dogs/Beagle.ts
export module Dogs {
  export Class Beagle {
    public Bark() {
      document.write('Woof');
    }
  }
}

// file:/app/DogPage.ts
import m = module('./Dogs/Beagle');
var b = new m.Dogs.Beagle();
b.Bark();

// file:/config.ts
var require: {baseUrl: '/app'};
```

These compile fine.  I also use RequireJS to load the files on my `Dogs.html` web page, using this HTML code:

```
<script src="/app/config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script data-main="DogPage" src="lib/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Again, this works fine and my use of the Beagle object results in "Woof" on the page.

Scenario2 (in which my problem arises):

I now have a 2nd project in which I want to use Beagle.ts, but I don't want to just copy the ts file, so I make a common copy in a 3rd project that I wish to use from Projects 1 & 2.

So my files look like this at development time:

```
/project1
  /Dogs.html
  /DogPage.ts

/project2
  /MoreDogs.html
  /MoreDogsPage.ts

/project3
  /app
    /Beagle.ts
```

and I plan to copy over Project3's `app` folder at deployment time so the structure look like this:

```
/project1
  /Dogs.html
  /DogPage.ts
  /app
    /Beagle.ts
```

How can I now link in Beagle.ts to my 2 apps so that I can actually compile them at development time and still have the paths work in production as described?  The paths as they are above would work at runtime, but I can't compile the code at dev time.

If I do this:

```
import m = module('../../../Dogs/Beagle');
```

it of course assumes a relative position on my hard drive at dev time, and would never work in production.

It seems I'm stuck and must maintain a copy of the code in both projects.  Maybe not a big deal for this contrived example, but my real project contains dozens of reusable class files.  How do organize this mess and still get it to compile?

UPDATE:
BASarat's proposal of a VS "linked file" resulted in this:

```
/*
Compile Error. 
See error list for details
 C:\proj2\app\MoreDogs.ts(2,34) : Incorrect reference: imported file: "./Dogs/Beagle" cannot be resolved.
C:/proj2/app/MoreDogs.ts(2,18): The name ''./Dogs/Beagle'' does not exist in the current scope
C:/proj2/app/MoreDogs.ts(2,18): A module cannot be aliased to a non-module type
C:/proj2/app/MoreDogs.ts(5,12): Expected var, class, interface, or module
```

*/

If the developer is using Visual Studio (which is an assumption I'd prefer not to make) this creates the illusion of a unified code based from the Solution Explorer perspective, but TypeScript does not compile using Solution Explorer's understanding of the code base, so the compile actually fails.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Although the question is a bit different, the answer you need is probably this: [Defining shared library in Typescript and Visual Studio Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548852/defining-shared-library-in-typescript-and-visual-studio-express) - bear in mind that the deployment needs to be considered, as per that example.

Comment: I checked that answer, and it looks to me like it suffers from the same limitation as BASarat's answer.  The typescript compiler doesn't seem to work with it, despite Solution Explorer's visual presentation of the file.

Comment: Actually, looking at my set-up more closely, I see that it's my use of Web Essentials and its "compile on save" feature that is causing the immediate failure.  It may be that Visual Studio will copy the file over when the final Typescript compile runs at build time?  But the syntax errors show up in the VS editor also and there is no intellisense, making me wonder how a developer is going to code using this approach anyway.  I don't think it's going to work.

Comment: it worked when I tested it in Visual Studio. Dragging the TypeScript file I want to reference from Solution Explorer onto the TypeScript file I'm working on gives me the relative path to the file automatically (instead of manually writing the `\\\<reference` comment.)

Comment: Running the build sequence in VS results in the same errors as those with Web Ess.'s compile on save.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @steve-fenton : Updated my answer above with the output error message.  The problem is not with the reference comment, but with the import() statement, which expects me to put in the relative path to the file AGAIN.  The problem with this is that the statement is in code and not a comment, and on my live site, the location of the file will be different, so the import() statement either fails in dev or fails in production.

Comment: @steve-fenton : Actually, there IS a problem with the link reference, as well.  When I drag it into the TS script as you describe, a relative reference is created in the script which points to the non-existent file (that is, to the location where VS has the link reference, but does not maintain a copy of the file).  So even that doesn't work.  Am I not communicating my problem clearly enough?

Answer (score 1):

You should reconsider your approach. You are developing a library, hence you should treat it as such. Trying to reference the source code of a shared resource is not a solution I would recommend. Furthermore you have already encountered issues trying to solve it this way.

Therefore, my recommendation is to treat your shared project as if it was an external library like i.e. jQuery. You should consider including the **output** of the shared project as a dependency of the other projects instead of referencing the source directly.

So how would you do this *and* keep making use of TypeScript? You could provide a definition file for your shared library containing all its definitions to the projects using it. Then require the output of the shared library somewhere in your app entry point to make sure those modules can be referenced. Finally use `require("module_name")` statements to include those modules where you need them.

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699940/how-can-i-import-an-external-file-with-typescript?rq=1) question used the same method I described above. I didn't flag your question as an exact duplicate however, but the idea is clearly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "Link to an external file" to both projects

http://www.basarat.com/2013/05/add-existing-item-as-link-in-visual.html

Comment: If the developer is using Visual Studio (which is an assumption I'd prefer not to make) this creates the illusion of a unified code based from the Solution Explorer perspective, but TypeScript does not compile using Solution Explorer's understanding of the code base, so the compile actually fails.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it appears that this suggestion does not achieve anything other than making the Solution Explorer look like the file is there when it isn't.

Comment: Provided link brings up a 404, and the text of the answer does not seem to adequately describe a solution. I'm using Visual Studio now, and I use a pre-build target to copy in linked TS files. While I can compile fine from running `tsc` from the command line, Visual Studio continues to show build errors when I `require` the linked TS files. The functionality mismatch is annoying.